# How to Add the List Items Statically When Preen on Button Click?

Tags: java, android

Suggest Me In Advance

The Problem Domain is

When i am CLick again The Two items Will add one more time in the listview,bt i dont need this duplication

```
 tvInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            tvInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.company_left_btn);
                            tvCompanies.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info_right_btn);
                            llDriverDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            llCompaniesDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        list.add("Big Truck Little Comp");
        list.add("Mani Info Tech");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It means even you click again and again your list should only show `Big Truck Little Comp` and `Mani Info Tech`

Comment: So... just don't add them??

Comment: At First Time I need The Two Items And after that  I dont Need...

Answer (score 0):

Many suggestions one of the easy ones would be to `disable` the button `

```
tvInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            tvInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.company_left_btn);
                            tvCompanies.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info_right_btn);
                            llDriverDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            llCompaniesDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        list.add("Big Truck Little Comp");
        list.add("Mani Info Tech");

    // Disableling Button
    tvInfo.setEnabled(false); 
                    }
                });`
```

Comment: on Click is There ,from that on Click I add The Items Dynamically next item onwards

Answer (score 0):

Do this,

```
boolean flag=true;

tvInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            tvInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.company_left_btn);
                            tvCompanies.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info_right_btn);
                            llDriverDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            llCompaniesDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  if(flag)
                  {
                      list.add("Big Truck Little Comp");
                      list.add("Mani Info Tech");
                      flag=false;
                     }
                        }
                    });
```

Please let me know if you have any feedback.

Comment: Thank U I got the OutPut

Comment: please accept the answer if you liked it.  Thanks  Manikanta Reddy